# Component and subcomponent out of sync in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component and subcomponent in Angular 2 (using Typescript) that's exhibiting a very puzzling behavior. The display that I'm looking for is something like:

> Object *object name*
>
> Up to *parent name* (123) (123)
>
> - *Child 1 name* (234)
> - *Child 2 name* (235)
> - *Child 3 name* (236)

What I'm getting instead is:

> Object *object name*
>
> Up *root name* (001) (123)
>
> - *Child 1 name* (234)
> - *Child 2 name* (235)
> - *Child 3 name* (236)

Here are the details:

The parent has something like this in its template:

```js
<div *ngIf="obj">
  Object {{obj.name}}
  <a (click)="setTag(obj.parent)">
    Up to <display [tag]="obj.parent"></display> ({{obj.parent}})
  </a>
  <div *ngIf="obj.children.length>0">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let child of obj.children">
         <display [tag]="child"></display>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

`SomeClass` looks like:

```js
export class SomeClass {
   tag: string;
   name: string;
   parent: string;
   children: string[];
}
```

where the parent component class looks something like this:

```js
obj: SomeClass

setTag(tag) {
    this.tag = tag
    setObj()
}

setObj() {
    this.objectService.getObject(this.tag)
    .then(obj => this.obj = obj)
}

setRoot() {
    this.objectService.getRoot()
    .then(obj => {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.tag = obj.tag;
     })
}

ngOnInit() {
    if (this.tag) {
        setTag(this.tag)
    } else {
        setRoot()
    }
}
```

and the child component template looks like this:

```js
<span *ngIf="obj">{{obj.name}} ({{obj.tag}})</span>
```

and the child component class contains:

```js
tag: string;
obj: SomeClass;

ngOnInit() {
    this.objectService.getObject(this.tag)
    .then(obj => this.obj = obj)
}
```

With the tag of the root as "001", the name field is "Root", and the tag of the current obj as "123", then the output of the parent template is something like "Up to Root (001) (123)". The *parent* component resolves the parent object just fine, but the *child* component always renders the value for the root concept. The very same child component works just fine in the loop, but not outside the loop.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Transclusion is a very baffling concept that you don't need in React (its just function arguments or prop members): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oEa6UueHsk

Comment: I appreciate the comment and the plug for ReactJS, but do you have any insight into why this isn't working in AngularJS?